# Read S2 button on Beaglebone Black

Tags: beaglebone-black

The beaglebone black board has an onboard button labeled as *S2*. I need to detect when a user pressed it to take certain action when it is pressed.

Can I access the S2 onboard button to detect when the user pressed it?

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Checking out the PDF, I can see it's wired to the board as it can be seen in page 6:

https://github.com/beagleboard/beaglebone-black/blob/master/BBB_SCH.pdf

It is connected to LCD_DATA2 which is wired to GPIO2_8

I can see in this table:

https://vadl.github.io/images/bbb/P8Header.png

It is wired to p8_43 on the board, but it is configured to control HDMI by default, so I have to disable HDMI by adding this line to `/boot/uEnv.txt`:

```
optargs=quiet capemgr.disable_partno=BB-BONELT-HDMI,BB-BONELT-HDMIN
```

Now I can access P8_43 using Adafruit GPIO library:

```py
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setup("P8_43", GPIO.IN)
GPIO.input("P8_43")
```